# MongoDB with PHP timeout when no results in cursor

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm doing some research on comparing MySQL and MongoDB performance in CRUD operations. 
When I'm executing this query:

```
$arrayFind = array(
  '$and' => array (
       array('ct_adult'   => array('$lte' => (int) $_GET['adult'] )),
       array('max_adult'  => array('$gte' => (int) $_GET['adult'] )),
       array('ct_child'   => array('$gte' => (int) $_GET['children'] )),
       array('min_people' => array('$lte' => (int) $people)),
       array('max_people' => array('$gte' => (int) $people)),
       array('dt_length'  => array('$gte' => (int) $_GET['length'])),
       array('code_food'  => (string) $_GET['food'])
    )      
);


$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://10.0.1.11:27010");

$db = $m->mydb;

$offers =  new MongoCollection($db, 'offers');;

$cursor = $offers->find($arrayFind)->limit(10);

foreach ($cursor as $document) {
   ...
}
```

I get timeout error when there are no results (script is waiting 30sec).

```
 Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorTimeoutException' with message '10.0.1.11:27010: cursor timed out
```

When there are results I'm getting them in time under 1 sec. I've tried to fix this problem using 'count()' method but it didn't work. Is there any solution for this timeout? How do you handle search results in mongo?

Comment: Will `while ($row = $cursor->getNext()) { ... }` instead of `foreach` fix it?

Comment: This is normally caused by either a very long programming loop (where you have that `...`) or by a very slow query. Judging by the criteria I would say this is a slow query...VERY SLOW QUERY

Comment: It's not very long (only echo with some values)

Comment: Can you do an explain on the query in terminal, also remove that `$and` condition, you don't need it

Comment: @MaximKhan-Magomedov: while ($row = $cursor->getNext()){ 
    echo $row['id'].' w cenie '.$row['price'].'<br/>';
}
   still the same timeout

Comment: @Sammaye in terminal problem doesn't exist

Comment: So you can do this query fine in console? Either way can you post the output of `explain`?

Comment: We had similar problems with random `cursor time out` errors and couldn't find its reason too. Regardless of query complexity and number of results. Maybe the problem is in PHP-Mongo driver.

Comment: What driver version is being used? edit: also you have a syntax error in that script: `$offers =  new MongoCollection($db, 'offers');;`

Comment: ok the problem is size of DB - collection has over 7.500.000 of documents and if I set limit to 10 it can find it in first thousands of docs, if not it scans whole collection which takes a lot of time. how can I optimize it?

Comment: db.offers.find({ ct_adult: { $gte: 5 } }).explain()  
    {  
            "cursor" : "BasicCursor",  
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 367045,
            "nscannedObjects" : 7678626,
            "nscanned" : 7678626,
            "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 7678626,
            "nscannedAllPlans" : 7678626,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nYields" : 0,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "millis" : 183680,
            "indexBounds" : {
    
            },
            "server" : "mongodb1:27010"
    }

Comment: It is using no indexes, add some indexes to your collection! But even then, that many range opreators won't be a pleasent query but lets start with adding indexes for those fields

Comment: unfortunately I have to check all of those parameters

Comment: Ok well lets start with `db.offers.ensureIndex({ ct_adult:1, max_adult:1, ct_child:1, min_people:1, max_people: 1, dt_length:1, code_food: 1})` but I can see where the schema could be merged in places, possibly..

Comment: @Sammaye thank you for your comment - I'm running this query now. What do you mean by saying schema could be merged in places?

Comment: Maybe min and max people could be some put into one figure so you are doing a range on a single field there? Things like that maybe